# How to add group by condition into a LogicalAggregate in calcite?

Tags: apache-calcite

For a sql like :

```
select count(*) from T group by c1,c2;
```

I parsed the sql to relnodes by apache calcite.what I'm trying to do is add a group by condition c3 to the relative LogicalAggregate and transform the sql to s

```
`elect count(*) from T group by c1,c2,c3;`
```

I'm wondering if there is any methods to edit a LogicalAggregate node.
THX